# How can I share my spring boot project with my team without having to upload it to a server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am working on a demo of a web application made in spring boot and the first phase is already completed, I would like my colleagues to be able to access it from their computers, but without having to deploy the app on a server or having to download the IDE on their computers.

What options are there? (I'm working with gradle)

I tried to use ip redirection so that they only put the ip of the computer and the port on which the app was launched so that in this way they have access, but it turns out that the company's firewall does not allow these intercommunications, I also tried to create an executable WAR, but I only saw examples for maven

Comment: you can share the jar or share the git

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GitHub or any other versioning tool and push your code into repository. And give access to your colleges.

Comment: I get it, but my goal is for them to be able to run the web app without downloading the code or some IDE to run it. I think I can temporarily put the app on railway and link it this with the github repo.